# Reading complex values from binary file into STL vector

Tags: c++

I have a binary file of a known quantity of complex far-field electric field values that is frequency dependent.  Two floating point values ( 32-bit ) per entry where the first float is the real part, the second is the imaginary ).  So the file size would be 2*4*(Number of frequencies).

1. From the C++11 standard, `std::vector` and `std::complex` are required (may be too strong of a word?) to be contiguous in memory.  Is this true for vectors of complex values?
2. Is it possible to load these complex values from the aforementioned binary file directly into the underlying dynamic array in a pre-allocated STL (`std::vector<std::complex>`) using the `std::ifstream` `read` function?

I should add that these files can be in the GB range.  It's not practical to allocate a fixed or dynamic array of `float`, read into, then copied into a `std::vector`.

Comment: This is possible, I would think - Use the complex<float> specialization, and overlay using placement new on the pre-sized vector buckets.

Comment: If you're seriously concerned with performance figure out how many entries are in the file then allocate a fixed sized array and read them directly into it.

Comment: you have to use `resize` first, which is not free. you wont gain much performance compare to say `emplace_back`

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, yngum I posit that reserving a vector size (eliminating resize overhead) provides all the benefits of vector functionality without the performance impact one would normally expect of a vector. Is this true?

Comment: @AK4749: Writing past the end of a vector is undefined behavior.

Comment: I'd probably just use `mmap` and use `reinterpret_cast<std::complex*>(...)`.  Zero overhead that way.  Or better yet, don't load the whole thing into memory at the same time unless you really have to.

Comment: much better solution with the mmap

Comment: Ok, maybe some background is in order.  I'm re-writing code from MATLAB (which is comically easy btw) into C++.  These files can range from ~10MB to 10GB.  Would parsing the file one entry at a time be ideal for compiled languages?  In MATLAB, that style of file IO is dreadfully slow, which is why reading with fread does it in one go.  Would reading in chunks at a time be the way to go for C++.  Speed is crucial in this application.  Another assumption is that the data would fit into the machine memory.  I'm trying to break myself of MATLAB habits by taking advantage of the speed of C++.

Comment: Optimization boils down to the same concepts in any language - minimize disk I/O (read it all in at once), bring next-used data as close to cpu register as possible (cache->ram->disk). You're going about it the right way, but @MooingDuck's technique is even faster than your proposed one I'd bet. As always, the more optimal, the fewer conveniences you have (lose vector capabilities). however, maybe you want to look into the MEX compiler in matlab? compile to c, then hand optimize what's left? No need to reinvent the wheel, I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go this route, you will need the following constructs:

1. `ifstream::read(&vec[0],nFreq * sizeof(complex<float>))`
2. [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax#Default_placement) for `std::complex` construction on preallocated memory
3. `vector<complex<float>> vec;
   vec.reserve(nFreq); // remember to catch exception if allocation fails due to huge files`

To further "prove" (no access to standard) the validity of your placement and file contents, a [quote from cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex):

```
For any complex number z, 
reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[0] is the real part of z and 
reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[1] is the imaginary part of z.

For any pointer to an element of an array of complex numbers p and
any valid array index i, 
reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i] is the real part of the complex number p[i], and
reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i + 1] is the imaginary part of the complex number p[i]
```

> These requirements essentially limit implementation of each of the three specializations of std::complex to declaring two and only two non-static data members, of type value_type, with the same member access, which hold the real and the imaginary components, respectively.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about placement new's relevance and usage?  Beginner here.

Comment: @SnakeEyes1482 as I'm sure you are aware, calling a constructor on an object in C++ allocates memory for it on the heap (using new). It guarantees nothing about where that memory is. Using placement new, you tell it exactly what piece of memory to use, because in your case you've already got it ready for it. Again, I'd look into MEX compiling your MATLAB code first, though. They made it basically for this reason